# How do I find *where* the ambiguous layout is located when I get the warning?

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout, uistoryboard

I get this warning whenever I build my app under iOS 7:

[image]

But whenever I click it, it doesn't bring me anywhere. I have a really large storyboard and I have no idea how to find that specific area that causes the warning. Does anyone know how I'd find the area?

Answer (score 4):

While you're running your app. debug area>press pause>type: po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: That tells me what the type of control is, but I want it to bring me to the specific one, I have dozens of UIButtons.

Comment: if there's no other way, try to display all of thier description (mybutton.description) look for thier memmory address(ex. 0x716ec30) and compare it which of them gets the ambiguous.

Comment: Can you tell what the asterisk in `_autolayoutTrace`'s output denotes?

Comment: if your referring to the image above,  its a pointer to an object that has their memory address *<UIButton:0x1234567>